# Tkinter GUI Freeze even after running background process in separate Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

UI is Freezing even after running the background process in separate Thread.
Db2Input = c1.fetchone() is taking few seconds to fetch the data from table as you can see it in the screenshot and I have recursive call to fetchData.

I thought Separate Thread won't have any interference with main Thread since I am not using any GUI element in FetchData() Function. Any suggestions...

```
from tkinter import *
import pyodbc
import connect
from datetime import datetime
import threading as th

class appLayout(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        
        self.masterPane = PanedWindow(self,bd=0,sashwidth =0 )
        self.leftPane   = Frame(self.masterPane,bg = 'orange',height = 400,width = 200,relief = 'raised')
        self.masterPane.add(self.leftPane)
        self.rightPane   = Frame(self.masterPane,bg = 'blue',height =400,width =500)
        self.masterPane.add(self.rightPane)
        self.masterPane.pack(fill = 'both',expand = True)
        
        self.AddButton()
        
    def on_enter(self,e):
        e.widget['background'] = 'green'

    def on_leave(self,e):
        e.widget['background'] = 'orange'
        
        
    def AddButton(self):
        btn1 = Button(self.leftPane, text = 'Dashboard   ', bg ='orange',relief ='flat',
                  bd =0,padx =10,pady=7,font ='Arial',fg='white',activebackground = 'green',command =self.SubmitThread) 
        
        btn2 = Button(self.leftPane, text = 'Dashboard   ', bg ='orange',relief ='flat',
                  bd =0,padx =10,pady=7,font ='Arial',fg='white')   
        
        btn3 = Button(self.leftPane, text = 'Dashboard   ', bg ='orange',relief ='flat',
                  bd =0,padx =10,pady=7,font ='Arial',fg='white') 
        
        btn1.grid(row =2,column =0,sticky ='nwe',ipady=5) 
        btn2.grid(row =3,column =0,sticky ='nwe',ipady=5)
        btn3.grid(row =4,column =0,sticky ='nwe',ipady=5)
        
        btn1.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        btn1.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        
        btn2.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        btn2.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        
        btn3.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        btn3.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    
    def SubmitThread(self):
        th.Thread(target = self.fetchData).start()
        

    
    def fetchData(self):
        connection = connect.connect('ADMIN','USER','Password')
        AS400Connection = connection.ToAS400Database()
        c1 = AS400Connection.cursor()
        sqlstatement = ("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE(QSYS2.JOB_INFO(JOB_STATUS_FILTER => '*OUTQ',\
                                JOB_USER_FILTER =>'{}') ))  WHERE JOB_TYPE ='BCH' AND JOB_NAME LIKE '%{}%'\
                                AND JOB_E00002 > '{}' ORDER BY JOB_E00002".format('USER','TEST','2021-06-11-10.25.00')) 
        print("Before Execution",datetime.now())
        c1.execute(sqlstatement)
        print("Before fetch",datetime.now())
        **Db2Input = c1.fetchone()**
        print("After fetch",datetime.now())
        c1.close()
        
        self.after(3000,self.fetchData)

app = appLayout()
app.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3cuA.png)

Comment: If `fetchData()` is run in its own thread, then you probably shouldn't use `self.after()`. You can afford to have: `while True: <do stuff> sleep(3)`

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for your quick response. I am new to python and tkinter and I have a follow-up question. I removed .after callback and it is working fine now. Could you please explain why .after callback was causing this issue because even .after just put it item in queue so I shouldn't Freeze UI. Also, when should one go for Thread and .after.

Comment: The .after() is part of tkinter and so must not be invoked from another thread.

Comment: @quamrana clear, Appreciate your help.